# Parallel SQL queries with aligned data, in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables, fruit, person and vegetable

Person

```
personID personName
-------- ----------
1        Ken
```

Fruit

```
personID fruitname
-------- -----
1        apple
1        orange
```

Vegetable

```
personID vegetableName
-------- -------------
1        carrot
1        tomato
1        potato
```

And I want the output to be like this...

```
personName fruitName vegetableName
---------- --------- -------------
1          apple     carrot
1          orange    tomato
1                    potato
```

It lessen the duplication of outputs.. is this even possible? can when I tried it before
the values keep repeating? Is their a way to avoid it?

Comment: It is a not so easy SQL question, but the kind how it was asked was noob style. Dave, please don't let SO's users eyes bleed by completely omitting formatting.

Comment: I think following @Daniel's edit, it's much less horrifying

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible if you also add a "position" column to the fruit and vegetables tables, and use this as an additional join column.

Records are not sorted in SQL. So, if you want the sorted, you ALWAYS need a sort criteria, because the SQL standard does not enforce any kind of sort order else.

If an alphabetical sort order is enought, you could dynamically add a position column by something like this (will not work in MS ACCESS, but something similar will do):

```
 SELECT f1.personid, f1.fruitname, count(*) as position
   FROM fruit f1 outer join fruit f2 on f1.fruitname = f2.fruitname 
                                    and f1.personid = f2.personid  
  WHERE f2.fruitname < f1.fruitname
  GROUP BY f1.personid, f1.fruitname
```

This query has a position, starting from 0, with the names "before".

Now you can do something like:

```
select f.personid, f.fruitname, v.vegetablename 
  from (*fruitquery*) f outer join (*vegetaryquery*) v on f.personid = v.personid
                                                      and f.positionid = v.positionid;
```

Comment: Isn't anybody going to say anything about the schema design problem, i.e., there are two separate tables for things that are really the same entity?

Comment: They are not the same entity. One entity has to be selected into col2, another in col3. And since no one manages fruits and vegetables in database, I assume this is only a placeholder, for some more complex real data.

Comment: They are foods, one of type fruit, the other of type vegetable. If these are only placeholders, then it's extremely ill-chosen, as it is a red herring that confuses the issue and makes it much harder to comprehend what is being described.